# How can I consume real-time data from alphavantage API in python's dictionary?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I try to use [alphavantage API](https://www.alphavantage.co) in my project. At the moment I am going to parse the JSON data in this way:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

def AlphaVantage(symbol):
    ts = TimeSeries(key='mykey')
    data = ts.get_intraday(symbol, interval='1min')

    print(str(data))


AlphaVantage('MSFT')
```

I would like to get only the most current data.

Comment: Does this API give real-time data? I just checked and it only returns data for the previous day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data returned is a tuple. There are two dictionaries inside the tuple. The first one contains the time and high/low values and the second contains the metadata. So, you can access the time:high/low values by data[0]. As you know that the keys in a dictionary are unsorted, so to only get the most recent data, you can use max of keys of this dictionary. So, the final code would be like this:
    print(str(data[0][max(data[0].keys())]))

Comment: With `print(str(data[0][max(data[0].keys())]))KeyError: 0` I get `KeyError: 0`

Comment: Are you sure? It works on my machine. Here's my complete code:     from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

def AlphaVantage(symbol):
    ts = TimeSeries(key=mykey)
    data = ts.get_intraday(symbol, interval='1min')
    print(str(data[0][max(data[0].keys())]))

AlphaVantage('MSFT')

Comment: Okay, now it works. Are you sure that this solution will always return the most recent data? As I have mentioned I am going to use it in my Django server and I have to be sure that it will be working properly every single time.

Comment: I have no reason to think that this will not work. Still, if you have any issues, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

If the API does not provide it, you can just grab the first one as the data is obviously sorted by date:

```
print(str(data['Time Series (1min)'][0]))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`